# Close button only on active tab of QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget, qtabbar

To save space in a `QTabWidget`, I would like to show the close icon only for the current tab, like e.g. Firefox is doing:

[image]

Is there a simple way using a style sheet, some thing like (not working like this)

```
QTabBar::tab::!selected::close-button {visible: false;}
```

or do I have to subclass `QTabWidget` to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You won't need to subclass anything, you can use `QTabWidget::tabBar()` method to obtain a reference (i.e. `QTabBar *`) to the tab bar associated with your `QTabWidget`. (Note that this method is no longer *protected*, so it can be accessed without subclassing the class)

```
QTabBar *tabBar = tabWidget->tabBar();
```

You can now use `tabBar` reference to *hide* close buttons on non-current tabs. For example to hide `i`th button, you can do:

```
tabBar->tabButton(i, QTabBar::RightSide)->hide();
```

So a simple workflow could be as follows:

- Connect `QTabWidget::currentChanged(int index)` signal to a slot.
- In that slot hide all close buttons other than the button at `index`.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I can make the buttons disappear with that. However, this does not modify the tab width. There's just some empty space in the tab: https://i.imgur.com/7yO4Cmi.png. Any idea how to reclaim that space?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `QTabWidget` to get access to the `QTabBar` widget using protected method `QTabWidget::tabBar`. Then you can connect to the `QTabBar::currentChanged` signal and hide close button for not selected tabs manually:

```
QTabBar::ButtonPosition closeSide =
        (QTabBar::ButtonPosition)style()->styleHint(QStyle::SH_TabBar_CloseButtonPosition, 0, this);

for (int i = 0; i < toolbar->count(); ++i)
{
    if (i != toolbar->currentIndex())
    {
        QWidget *w = toolbar->tabButton(i, closeSide);
        w->hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: `QTabWidget::tabBar` is no longer _protected_.

Comment: In Qt 4.8 it was.

Answer (score 0):

hide() leaves empty space for the invisible close button. This looks funny.
Set the width to 0 instead.